# Persistent Navigation rail in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I am facing issue in integrating persistent navigation rail with nested go router in flutter web, please let me know how to do it. I have applied all necessary code but still could not find it.

I am expecting persisting Navigation rail while nesting multiple page,I have done with persistent navigation rail part, but cannot get nested navigation, as it works for first item in rail with nested pages linking, but for 2nd item in rail it does not work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation Rail handles its own navigation where you can change the view based on an array of Widgets to switch between, rather then routing you would change the current widget being displayed. And then you can push and pop with go router, with this navigation rail being the root.

```
...
final views = [
    View1(),
    View2()
]

Widget build(BuildContext) {

    return Row(
        children: [
            NavigationRail(
                labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.all,
                onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
                    setState(() {
                    currentPageIndex = index;
                    });
                },
                groupAlignment: -1.0,
                destinations: <NavigationRailDestination>[
                    NavigationRailDestination(
                        icon: Icon(
                            Icons.groups_2_outlined,
                            size: 35.0,
                            color: theme.colorScheme.onSurface,
                        ),
                        label: CText(
                            'View 1',
                        ),
                    ),
                    NavigationRailDestination(
                        icon: Icon(
                            Icons.book_outlined,
                            size: 35.0,
                            color: theme.colorScheme.onSurface,
                        ),
                        label: Text('View 2'),
                    ),
                ],
                selectedIndex: currentPageIndex,
            ),            
            VerticalDivider(
                thickness: 1,
                width: 1,
                color: theme.colorScheme.outlineVariant,
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: views[currentPageIndex],
            )
        ],
    );
}
```